Migration material-ui version 4 into mui v5
I have followed up material Ui documentation for migration of material Ui from version 4 to version 5.
But getting errors while running this command -
npx @mui/codemod@latest v5.0.0/preset-safe <path>
With using Node.js v20.11.0.
Node.js v20.11.0
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'core-js/modules/web.dom-collections.iterator.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\my\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\15796\node_modules\@mui\codemod\node\v5.0.0\adapter-v4.js
- C:\Users\my\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\15796\node_modules\@mui\codemod\node\v5.0.0\preset-safe.js
- C:\Users\my\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\15796\node_modules\@mui\codemod\node_modules\jscodeshift\src\Worker.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\my\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\15796\node_modules\@mui\codemod\node\v5.0.0\/adapter-v4.js:1:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\my\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\15796\node_modules\@mui\codemod\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:117:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (C:\Users\my\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\15796\node_modules\@mui\codemod\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:121:7)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\my\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\15796\node_modules\@mui\codemod\node\v5.0.0\/preset-safe.js:8:40)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\my\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\15796\node_modules\@mui\codemod\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:117:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (C:\Users\my\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\15796\node_modules\@mui\codemod\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:121:7)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at setup (C:\Users\my\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\15796\node_modules\@mui\codemod\node_modules\jscodeshift\src\Worker.js:91:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\my\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\15796\node_modules\@mui\codemod\node_modules\jscodeshift\src\Worker.js:45:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\my\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_npx\\15796\\node_modules\\@mui\\codemod\\node\\v5.0.0\\adapter-v4.js',
    'C:\\Users\\my\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_npx\\15796\\node_modules\\@mui\\codemod\\node\\v5.0.0\\preset-safe.js',
    'C:\\Users\\my\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_npx\\15796\\node_modules\\@mui\\codemod\\node_modules\\jscodeshift\\src\\Worker.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v20.11.0
All done.
Results:
0 errors
0 unmodified
0 skipped
0 ok
Time elapsed: 34.054seconds


Receiving this error. I also try to re-install my packages for that and install core-js library too but still issue persists. "core-js": "^3.37.0" this version is used.

Hi, Please let me know if anyone face same type of issue or know the solution.
